# Tap area of AirPlay button in MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, ipad, airplay, mpvolumeview

I have a MPVolumeView with AirPlay button. When I tap the AirPlay button in the center of the icon it does not respond. It seems like the tap isn't recognized. When I tap the icon on the right side of the icon the popover is displayed correctly. (iPad/iOS5)

Why is this?

Comment: i concur that the radius of the airplay component of a MPVolumeView seems to be smaller than the HIG's 44x44 minimum